# Programmatically determine Gradle version from within Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

How can I retrieve the version of Gradle itself **programmatically** from within a Gradle plugin?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just found out one can get at it using either

- `getProject().getGradle().getGradleVersion()`
  [Javadoc](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/) and [DSL reference](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle.html#org.gradle.api.invocation.Gradle) for the Gradle core type which contains the version. Accordinng to the javadoc getVersion will never return null.

or

- `Plugin.class.getPackage().getImplementationVersion()`
  This is plain groovy/java [class-based](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) and depends on the classloader and provided Manifest.

Answer (score 0):

This question appeared as the first result when I Googled for it.

There's a class - GradleVersion that'll do the job as well. So

```
GradleVersion.current();
```

will return the same as

```
getProject().getGradle().getGradleVersion()
```